# replace() not replacing string contents of a file, even though file is defined as output

Tags: python

I am trying to replace all square brackets with braces as it's easier to convert for other use in other languages (such as Lua). The issue is, is that none of the square brackets get replaced with braces. I even did a find search in the file to see if there were any braces but none at all. The code below is just a simple pixel-color code using Python Pillow.

In the last two lines, is where I try to attempt to replace all square brackets with braces, which doesn't work.

```py
with open("imgoutput.json", "a+") as output:
    output.write(jsonStr)
    filedata = output.read()

filedata.replace('[','{')
filedata.replace(']','}')
```

Comment: You need to modify the string before you write it to the file. Modifying a string that you have read from a file doesn't automatically cause the file to be updated with the modified contents.

Comment: When you write the file, `output` points to the last byte written, so there's nothing in `filedata`. Do `output.seek(0)` before `output.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only replacing stuff in the variable `filedata`, you need to write the changes to your `.json` file. For this you can use `x.write(filedata)`

```py
...
with open("imgoutput.json", "r") as output:
    filedata = output.read()

filedata = filedata.replace('[','{')
filedata = filedata.replace(']','}')

input = open("imgoutput.json", "w")
input.write(filedata)
input.close()
```

Something to note; `.replace()` doesnt change the active variable, it makes a new one. So the correct syntaxs is `a = b.replace() || a = a.replace`

Comment: Noticed you wrote input-write instead of input.write, so I fixed it but now it writes nothing to the file.

Comment: The last 2 line causes the file to be blank

Comment: @vxsqi I updated the code to fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

You have to move your read pointer position within the file.

Test code:

```
with open("hello.txt", "a+") as fp:
    fp.write("Hello World!")
    
    strdata = fp.read()
    print("Test1: %s" % strdata)
    
    fp.seek(0,0)
    strdata = fp.read()
    print("Test2: %s" % strdata)
```

Results:

```
Test1: 
Test2: Hello World!
```